# Awkward host name when running Erlang getting started program

Tags: cookies, windows-7, erlang

On Windows 7 I have entered and compiled the "tut17" program from the page:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#id68449

I set the HOME variable to "C:\Users\Name" and I have created a cookie file ".erlang.cookie" in the "C:\Users\Name" directory.

I have started two command prompts as described on the above page.  The problem is that the host name is "Name-PC".  So when I start the ping process I get a message as follows:

```
(ping@Name-PC)2> tut17:start_ping(pong@Name-PC).
* 1: variable 'PC' is unbound
```

How can I get around this problem (presumably) with the hyphen in the host name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `pong@Name-PC` between `'` (single quotes). `'pong@Name-PC'` will be interpreted as a single atom rather than the atom `pong@Name` minus the variable `PC`.